# User notifications/subscriptions to content

Tags: emails

I'm quoting on a project where users need to receive email notifications/subscriptions to content updates.

Essentially they should be able to login to the site and once on a page subscribe to that page to be notified when the entry is updated.

Is there a way to do this in Craft? If so what would be the best approach?

Comment: I'd also like to know, besides "Create a custom module...". Currently using MailChimp Subscribe plugin with MailChimp Tags feature. Each Tag corresponds to a Craft Channel.

Comment: We did exactly this on a Craft site recently. It very much requires a custom module/plugin. Think about the practicalities - an editor doesn't want everyone to be emailed if they need to fix a typo in the entry, so in my opinion there needs to be a manual process somewhere. In our case, we added a button to the sidebar of the entry screen to trigger the email and preview the audience list.